# Drush command to delete content going out of memeory. What can I do?

Tags: drush, nodes

I have implemented drush hooks to build a drush command that deletes a lot of legacy nodes. It basically does a node_delete on a lot of nodes in a loop. However, I have the memory limit set to ~380MiB in settings.php and when I run the command to delete large number of nodes, say 100 000, drush terminates abnormally with an error indicating that it ran out of memeory. This happens by the time it deletes 20000 nodes. I have looked around and checked the definition of [node_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete/6). In the definition there is a comment about the possibility of going out of memory.

I tried unsetting variables, and I tried doing node_load(NULL,NULL,TRUE)-- as suggested one drupaler on this forum-- hoping to release some memory every number of iterations but this did not work. So is there anything I can do? I am trying to avoid breaking it into chunks for ease of release.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code for `node_delete_multiple()` it does a [`node_load_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7).  While this seems strange, it has to do this so that it can invoke all of the proper hooks so that other modules have the full `$node` object in order to do their thing (eg, delete the attached field data).

Because Drupal uses aggressive static caching to avoid redundant database accesses, memory usage can swell.  This can't be freed or disabled.  If this becomes an issue, you can do temp edits to the EntityControllers to comment out the static caches.  You could also make a temp edit to [`drupal_static()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7) to effectively disable it.

I would come up with a good [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) to get the list of nodes to delete.  This will just give you back the nids.

Suck out the nids, and trim the array to some limit.

Call [`node_delete_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7) on the result.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', $bundle)
  ->addCondition(...)
  ->execute();

$nids = array_slice($entities['node'], 0, 1000);

print 'Deleting ' . count($nids) . ' nodes ... ';

if (!empty($nids)) {
  node_delete_multiple($nids);
}

print "done\n";
```

Put this in a standalone PHP and execute is from drush, eg

```
drush -u 1 scr nuke_everything.php
```

Run it until everything is gone.

The above solution is for Drupal 7, but the approach is essentially the same for Drupal 6.  You would do a `db_query()` to get the nids, and then loop through and call `node_delete()` on each.  However, Drupal 6 also does a full `node_load()`, too.  In this instance, it does bypass its static cache, but this doesn't mean that modules aren't also doing any static caching.  For Drupal 6, you would need to chase all of the possible [`hook_nodeapi('delete')`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) and look for static caching and static caching in any functions that get called, and do temp edits.

Comment: It's drupal 6. Sorry I failed to mention that.  I have done this in drupal 7 for a site I have. In fact I also wrote a drush command that uses pure MySQL to get all the tables from which I need to delete. It runs fine. But my question iit is running out of memory and how to make it work with node delete

Comment: @Al86  The approach can be adapted for Drupal 6 by using db_query() and looping through nids with node_delete().  Unfortunately, unless you want to start profiling with xdebug, I am not sure what you can do.  Even then, node_delete is going to invoke a lot of hooks so modules have the opportunity to do their thing.  I don't really see what option you have, other than doing the deletes in batches rather than all at once.

Comment: This is what meant. I have already written this for d6 too. I took it out of the delete all module and modified it. But all I want to know is why node delete goes out of memory and if there is a away to release memory. Thank you

Comment: @Al86  Tried to address via some edits.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the memory_limit for PHP cli.

If you're in Ubuntu-based you have to update this file

`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

Search for `memory_limit` and increase the value.

Comment: How can I possibly know how much I need?

Comment: What is the current value now? You could try to set it to 256M.